# Why is it thrown java.lang.InstantiationException?

Tags: java, reflection, constructor, inner-classes

Look at following code:

```
public class Outer {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        new Outer().greetWorld();
    }

    private void greetWorld() throws Exception {
        System.out.println(Inner.class.newInstance());
    }

    public class Inner {
        public Inner () {}
        public String toString(){
            return "HelloWorld";
        }
    }
}
```

Why is it thrown `java.lang.InstantiationException` ?
After all, nested class `Inner` has nully constructor. Can someone explain it?

Comment: `javap -c Outer$Inner` would explain why.

Comment: I would like to notice that a public default constructor may be absent which makes inner instance construction via Reflection API impossible. You definitely need to handle the `NoSuchMethodException` exception

Answer (score 6):

The [implicit] first argument in an inner's class' constructor is a reference to its enclosing class. When calling it via reflection, you need to explicitly provide it:

```
private void greetWorld() throws Exception {
    System.out.println(Inner.class.getConstructors()[0].newInstance(this));
}
```

Comment: are you sure that it will compile? `newInstance` should be called on a `Constructor` instance, not `Class`

Comment: `System.out.println(Inner.class.getConstructor(Outer.class).newInstance(this));`

Comment: Got ahead of myself there... Edited and fixed.

Comment: @JBNizet, it will throw an exception if there is no public default constructor

Comment: @AndrewTobilko sure. But there is one.

Answer (score 0):

Your class Inner needs to be instantiated, one solution would be to declare it static.

```
static class Inner {
    public Inner () {}
    public String toString(){
        return "HelloWorld";
    }
}
```